# Return additional properties using reduce and spread operator JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the reduce function below to count how many times a players name is mentioned and then list them based on who was mentioned the most to the least.

I am trying to return the 2nd property  `` [`${value.subtitles[0].name} + ${index}`] : value.subtitles[0].url `` with my object and sort it. However it is not sorting properly. When only returning the first property `[value.title]: (acc[value.title] || 0) + 1,` everything works as intended. But the second property is making it sort incorrectly. It is supposed to be sorting based on the title property value which is an integer of how many times that player was mentioned, from most to least. Why is this happening?

Thanks for the help!

```
const players = [
  {
    "title": "Mike",
    "titleUrl": "https://mikegameplay",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Mike Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/mike"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Cindy",
    "titleUrl": "https://cindy",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Cindy Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/cindy"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Mike",
    "titleUrl": "https://mike",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Mike Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/mike"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Haley",
    "titleUrl": "https://Haley",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Haley Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/haley"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Haley",
    "titleUrl": "https://Haley",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Haley Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/haley"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Haley",
    "titleUrl": "https://Haley",
    "subtitles": [
      {
        "name": "Haley Channel",
        "url": "https://channel/haley"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
const counts = players.reduce((acc, value, index) => ({
   ...acc,
   [value.title]: (acc[value.title] || 0) + 1,
   [`${value.subtitles[0].name} + ${index}`] : value.subtitles[0].url
}), {});

const sortedValues = [];

for (const value in counts) {
    sortedValues.push([value, counts[value]]);
};

sortedValues.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

console.log(sortedValues)
```

Comment: Can you show the json you want pls?

Comment: I don't get what you intended to use the second property for. It works without that, so leave it out? What's the problem?

Comment: @Bergi The second property is to get the link, that I later use in an anchor tag to link to the players profile.

Comment: @EngineerForFun What does that have to do with counting the number of times a title occurs?

Comment: Wait is the input an array that contains the *same* objects multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var groupBy = function (xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var pl = groupBy(players, "title");
console.log(pl);

let sortable = [];
for (var item in pl) {
  sortable.push([item, pl[item].length, pl[item][0].subtitles[0].url]);
}

sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortable));
```

result

```
[["Haley",3,"https://channel/haley"],["Mike",2,"https://channel/mike"],["Cindy",1,"https://channel/cindy"]]
```